# Is it ok to delete the WCH.CN folder?

Tags: windows-10, arduino

So I have a windows 10 dell laptop which is 64 bit and recently I was going to my `C:\` drive to delete the `windows.old` folder but I noticed another folder called `WCH.CN` with another folder inside it called `CH341SER` and I wanted to delete this folder as I am not familiar with it and what it does so it is okay to delete `WCH.CN` folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely delete that folder. It is the location where the setup program for the "CH341 (USB=>SERIAL chip) V3.4" driver is decompressed.

That driver is used for a USB controller commonly found on 3rd party Arduinos.